# How to select Rows not on HOLDLOCK by another transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am writing a Multi-instance background service, where I would like to process the recent data first, for this I am selecting top 10 records in a batch and marking them from a instance specific id, and then reading them for processing,

This process runs in multiple instances, thus there is a chance of records to be picked by more than one instance and I could generate duplicate results.

To avoid this I would like instance to pick records which are not already put on HOLDLOCK

My current update and select statement looks like this:

```
ALTER PROC dbo.GetRecordsForInstance @RecordCount INT = 10, @InstanceId varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    update t with (ROWLOCK) set t.ProcessingStatus =@InstanceId, t.IsProcessing = 1
    from SomeTable t 
    join 
    (
        SELECT TOP (@RecordCount) Col1, Col2 
        FROM dbo. SomeTable with (ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE IsProcessing = 0 and IsCompleted = 0
        ORDER BY LastModifiedOn
    ) t1 on t.Id = t1.Id
    
    SELECT * FROM SomeTable with (ROWLOCK) where ProcessingStatus = @InstanceId
END;
```

Comment: I guess you can take a look on READPAST-hint , e.g. https://www.sqlshack.com/explore-the-sql-query-table-hint-readpast/

Comment: looks promising , let me try.

Comment: Where are you releasing the ROWLOCK?

Comment: @jdweng That's not how it works. The end of the transaction will release the locks. Each statement runs in an implicit auto-commit transaction anyway

Answer (score 3):

You can [use the `READPAST` hint](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/building-reusable-queues-part-2/) to skip already-locked rows.

You cannot use it with `SERIALIZABLE` though, you would need to downgrade the isolation level to `REPEATABLEREAD`. This is not an issue in this case, as the extra guarantee is only regarding new data.

Further improvements:

- You can update the `t1` derived table directly, there is no need to rejoin. Just select out all columns from that inner table.
- You can combine the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` using `OUTPUT`.
- To prevent deadlocks in this type of query, you **must** have an index on your table over the columns which you are querying by `(IsProcessing, IsCompleted, LastModifiedOn)` preferably with `INCLUDE` columns also.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetRecordsForInstance
  @RecordCount INT = 10,
  @InstanceId varchar(max)
AS

UPDATE t
SET
  ProcessingStatus = @InstanceId,
  IsProcessing = 1
OUTPUT inserted.*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (@RecordCount)
      *
    FROM dbo.SomeTable t WITH (ROWLOCK, REPEATABLEREAD, READPAST)
    WHERE IsProcessing = 0 and IsCompleted = 0
    ORDER BY LastModifiedOn
) t;
```

Comment: Do I need to wrap it with Transaction?

Comment: No there is no need, as the whole thing is one statement

Comment: Why did you put HoldLock ? as far as I am able to obtain ROWLOCK and READPAST isn't it good?

Comment: getting following error: 'You can only specify the READPAST lock in the READ COMMITTED or REPEATABLE READ isolation levels'

Comment: Forgot that, need to change to `REPEATABLEREAD`